# Why the value is not binding with the value property?

Tags: reactjs

I'm prepolutaing some values from my other UI page to this UI. On UI I'm getting the values but it is not binding with the value property. On submit button, null value is assigning.

```
if (this.props.userInfo.account.user !== undefined) {
    // const res1 = splitByWhitespace('{this.props.userInfo.account.user.userName}')
    // console.log('res1 = ' + JSON.stringify(res1, null, 4))
    return (
        <ReformContext themes={{ default: defaultTheme }} validations={defaultValidations} >
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <ToastContainer />
                <button type='submit' className='Save-Continue-Button'>
                    {Resource.SaveNContinue}
                </button>
                <div className='tab-content col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1'>
                    <h2> {Resource.HEAD_RegisterCustomerHeader} </h2>
                    <hr />
                    <div className='form-horizontal'>
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <Text name='FirstName' isRequired placeholder={Resource.PH_EnterFirstName} />
                            <Text name='LastName' isRequired placeholder={Resource.PH_EnterLastName} />
                            <Text name='OrganizationName' isRequired placeholder={Resource.PH_EnterOrganizationName} 
                               value={this.props.userInfo.account.user.organizationName} />
                            <Text name='EmailId' isRequired isEmail placeholder={Resource.PH_EnterEmail}
                                value={this.props.userInfo.account.user.emailId} />
                            <Text name='PhoneNo' isRequired hasMaxlength={10} hasMinlength={10} placeholder={Resource.PH_EnterPhoneNo} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </ReformContext>
    )
}
```

Code for this.handleSubmit:

```
 handleSubmit = (data) => {
    this.addCustomer(data);
}

addCustomer(customer) {
    axios.post(json.map(function (api) { return api.RegisterCustomer; }),
        {
            'FirstName': customer.FirstName,
            'LastName': customer.LastName,
            'OrganizationName': customer.OrganizationName,
            'EmailId': customer.EmailId,
            'PhoneNo': customer.PhoneNo
        })
}
```

Comment: Which value is null?

Comment: organizationName and emailId @RossAllen

Comment: What does `this.handleSubmit` do? We can't see what happens when you submit the form and how `this.props.userInfo.account.user.organizationName` changes, so it's difficult to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: this.handleSubmit is basically adding data into cosmos DB. @RossAllen